# proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount failed service

Tags: linux, service, startup, systemd

I have just installed systemd and I have a failing service, proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount

I've seen here it's a part of systemd:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/units/proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount

Is this file important ? How do I solve the activation issue ?

Below my systemctl status

```
Last login: Mon Apr 13 23:13:19 2015 from nor75-18-82-241-236-193.fbx.proxad.net
svassaux@vps127101:~$ systemctl status
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount -> '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/proc_2dsys_               2dfs_2dbinfmt_5fmisc_2eautomount'
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount - Arbitrary Executable File Formats File Syste               m Automount Point
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount; static               )
   Active: failed (Result: resources)
    Where: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
     Docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
```

Comment: Please ask the moderators to migrate this to unix.stackexchange.com. It's not a programming question.

Answer (score 7):

For those who want to *disable* `proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount` (if you’re in, say, a containerized environment where autofs is not available), note that `systemctl disable` won’t work, but

```
systemctl mask proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
```

does.

Answer (score 3):

For using `.automount` unit of systemd, systemd tries to open **/dev/autofs**. In case autofs file system  is not available on your system, all `.automount` unit files fails to start.
So first ensure your system does have auto file system support.